# Projection onto subspaces in Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, projection

Let $M$ and $N$ be two closed subspaces of the Hilbert space $H$ and $x\in H$. Put $y=P_M(x)$ and $z=P_N(x)$. Is it true that $x$ lies in  the subspace spanned by $y$ and $z$? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Certainly not. Take for example $M$ and $N$ eigenspaces of a selfadjoint compact operator with infinitely many eigenvalues to eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ and $x$ an eigenvector to an eigenvalue $\lambda_3$ where $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2\neq \lambda_3$. Then $P_M(x)=P_N(x)=0$

Comment: Is (1,1,1) in the span of (1,0,0) and (0,1,0)?

Answer (score 1):

For this to be true one needs to put some condition on the subspaces $M$ and $N$. Suppose that $H$ is not one-dimensional, and pick an arbitrary vector $v \in H$. Then set $M = N = \text{span}\{ v \}$. Now pick a vector $x \notin M$. In this case the subspace spanned by $y = P_{M}(x)$ and $z = P_{N}(x) = y$ will be either $\{ 0 \}$ or $M$, neither of which contains $x$.

A bit more generally, suppose that there is a non-zero vector $x \in H$, with $P_{M}(x) = 0$ and $P_{N}(x) = 0$, then $x$ will not lie in the span of $P_{M}(x)$ and $P_{n}(x)$.

I am afraid that the precise condition on $M$ and $N$ for your claim to hold is somewhat tautological. Namely, your claim is true if and only if
\begin{equation}
 M + N := \{ y + z \in H| x \in M, z \in N \} \equiv H.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

consider $M= \mbox{Span}[1,0,0]^T$ and $N= \mbox{Span}[0,1,0]^T$ and the vector 
$x=[1,1,1]^T$